# Beer swapping online?

Tags: recommendations, distribution

I've tried hundreds of beers in recent years. But it starts to get expensive buying some beers less accessible online. Is there any site about swapping beers between people of different countries?

Comment: I don't believe there is one. You can always start your own website :).

Comment: I would love to do this, since I live in the Netherlands where we can't get many of the great American beers (do love that Stone is opening up in Berlin btw). But I have to wonder whether it is legal to do this...

Comment: I imagine it would be really complicated (and expensive) to trade beers internationally. Some countries impose heavy taxes on alcohol import.

Comment: BeerAdvocate ISO:FT
Reddit Beer

Answer (score 4):

Check out [BeerTrade](http://www.reddit.com/r/beertrade/).  It's not specifically limited to swapping between countries, but there is no reason you couldn't organize something there. There are about 10,000 people watching that subreddit currently.

Comment: I am a huge fan of this sub-reddit and recommend trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

BeerAdvocate has some swapping features including the ability to create a "want" and "have" list of beers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on [BeerRate forum](http://www.ratebeer.com/Forums/Forum-5.htm).

Answer (score -1):

In the US, it's completely illegal for regular people to ship alcohol through the US Post Office inside the US. You can if you are a certified wine/beer/spirits shipper through UPS or Fedex or get someone to do it for you. That just inside the country! I am a certified shipper for my (defunct) winery and I've tried shipping wine internationally several times and it was so expensive we all decided not to do it. You can do it under the table (illegally) but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Pretty sure it's much easier in the EU.